# How would you optimize this sql query

Tags: php, sql

Can anybody help me in optimizing this query,

```
SELECT
A,
B
FROM  tableAA
WHERE  (C IN (SELECT D
       FROM tableBB
       WHERE (E IN (SELECT F
                FROM tableCC
                WHERE (G='$selected')
                )
         )

       )
) AND (G=$SELECTED22)
ORDER BY
A;
```

WHEREAS

TABLEAA : 1 million enteries

TABLEBB : 22 million enteries

TABLECC : 79 million enteries

it works but take too much time, almost 30 sec

Is there any other way to right this?

Comment: Indexes. Indexes. Indexes.

Comment: try simplifying your query by using inner join and using indexes

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The first step would be to use JOIN instead of nested queries:

```
SELECT A, B
FROM tableAA
JOIN tableBB on C=D
JOIN tableCC on E=F
WHERE G='$selected'
ORDER BY A
```

Then make sure all your tables are indexed correctly. It's even better if `C` and `D` have the same name, as you can then just use `USING (C)` (and same for E/F)

Answer (score 0):

Inner join rather than IN keyword. After that, ensure you have indexes set properly (ORDER BY can be expensive without a proper index)

Answer (score 0):

1)first, make sure all of your table contained primary key
2)second, try not to use keyword 'IN' because it will perform full table scan, always prevent full table scan for fast query

3)Check your A and B is it already indexed ~

```
SELECT A, B
FROM  tableAA
INNER JOIN tableBB with (nolock) on C=D //only if C and D doesnt contain and null value
//if there are null value, use left outer join
INNER JOIN tableCC with (nolock) on E=F //only if E and F doesnt contain any null value
//if there are null value, use left outer join
WHERE G='$selected'
ORDER BY A;
```